# How to reset a cloud Postgres DB as if it was just created before each demo deployment?

Tags: postgresql, deployment, reset, demo

I was using Heroku for projects in development.

Heroku has a great option to reset Postgres DB: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-heroku-postgres-using-cli#pg-reset.

Now I'm using other cloud services for Postgres hosting which don't have such feature.

Since during the development phases the DB can change considerably I would like to automatically reset the DB during each deployment before being filled again by my new code.

How do I reset the DB (as if it was just created) if the hosting doesn't provide me a CLI/API to do it but only a web interface and of course the connection string?